# Eliminar caracteres en una columna de un data frame en Python

Tags: python, dataframe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola, buen día.

Por favor, si serían tan amables de ayudarme a eliminar los caracteres marcados en rojo en la imagen: 003: , 006: , etc.

El dataframe lo he ralizado con data que tengo en archivos excel, tengo 12 archivos que corresponden a 12 años, desde el 2007 al 2018. Ya logré consolidarlos en uno solo con el siguiente código:

```
dataframes = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10, df11, df12]

join = pd.concat(dataframes)

join.to_excel('Data Consolidada.xlsx')
```

Pero quiero eliminar esos caracteres al inicio.

Estuve intentando aplicar este código, para el df1, pero no sé qué parámetros colocar después del split y el apply.

```
df1["Programa"] = df1["Programa"].str.split( ).apply(lambda i: .join(i[:]))
```

Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Podrías incluir por favor el código de como has establecido tu dataframe porfavor. Gracias!

Comment: Podrias agregar lo que has intentado por favor (aunque no funcione)? De ese modo nos demostraras que eres parte del esfuerzo por resolver tu propia duda y mas gente querra responderte ya que sabremos que no te estamos haciendo la tarea.

Comment: @DaniCifuJim, ya puse el código :)

Comment: @DanteS., ya agregué lo que intenté y no me ha funcionado. En realidad he estado probando con muchos códigos y no me han funcionado o no he sabido colocar los parámetros adecuadamente.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que cada df es un diccionario cuya clave corresponde a cada uno de los títulos de la tabla y cada valor para dicha clave es la casilla según la línea (df) con la que estemos trabajando. Tratando cada valor como un string, podrías quitar los números de la siguiente forma:

El método `split` te devolverá una lista donde cada uno de los elementos será una cadena que surge al usar : como separador. De forma que según tu tabla te devolverá una lista con dos elementos, uno el nº y otro el nombre del programa.
Hecho esto tomamos dicha lista quedándonos únicamente con el segundo elemento (nombre del programa) y lo guardas en df1["programa"]

```
list_programa = df1["programa"].split(":")
df1["programa"] = list_programa[1]
```

Puedes implementar esto mediante un bucle para que se aplique sobre todos los df (líneas):

```
for df in datframes: 
    lista = df["programa"].split(":")
    df["programa"] = lista[1]
```

Pd. Si por el contrario a como he planteado, no dudes en preguntarme lo que sea por si pudiese ayudarte de alguna forma!
Suerte!